# How to set the behavior of IDEA downloading plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea

When IDEA downloads the kotlin plugin, it does not use the user's maven settings. How should I set the download behavior of IDEA?

IDEA's behavior is contrary to Maven settings:

1. Do not download from the configured mirror repository
2. Do not download to the set local directory.

How should I make the IDEA download plugin consistent with the Maven settings?

I can't view the output information downloaded by IDEA, I only know what IDEA downloaded. Based on this, I guess IDEA is downloading the Kotlin plugin.

```
└─org
    ├─jetbrains
    │  ├─annotations
    │  │  └─13.0
    │  ├─externalAnnotations
    │  │  └─com
    │  │      └─fasterxml
    │  │          └─jackson
    │  │              └─core
    │  │                  ├─jackson-core
    │  │                  │  └─2.9.6-an1
    │  │                  └─jackson-databind
    │  │                      └─2.9.6-an1
    │  ├─intellij
    │  │  └─deps
    │  │      └─trove4j
    │  │          └─1.0.20200330
    │  ├─kotlin
    │  │  ├─kotlin-annotations-jvm
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-build-common
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-compiler
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-daemon
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-daemon-client
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-dist-for-jps-meta
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-jps-plugin
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-main-kts
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-maven-allopen
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-maven-lombok
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-maven-noarg
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-maven-sam-with-receiver
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-maven-serialization
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-native-utils
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-project
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-reflect
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-script-runtime
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-scripting-common
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-scripting-compiler
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-scripting-js
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-scripting-jvm
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-stdlib
    │  │  │  ├─1.5.0
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-stdlib-common
    │  │  │  ├─1.5.0
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-stdlib-jdk7
    │  │  │  ├─1.5.0
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-stdlib-jdk8
    │  │  │  ├─1.5.0
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-util-io
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  ├─kotlin-util-klib
    │  │  │  └─1.7.22
    │  │  └─kotlin-util-klib-metadata
    │  │      └─1.7.22
    │  └─kotlinx
    │      └─kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm
    │          └─1.5.0
    ├─jline
    │  ├─jline
    │  │  └─3.3.1
    │  └─jline-parent
    │      └─3.3.1
    └─sonatype
        └─oss
            └─oss-parent
                └─9
```

Comment: What exact settings do you use in Maven? Do you have the same problem with Java?

Comment: @vanyochek I set up maven's mirror repository and the disk path of the local repository. Java should not need a plugin, just use the JDK directly.

Comment: Please file an issue https://kotl.in/issue.